# How to install sasl on windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip

I wanted to install sasl using pip.

System specification:

- Python 3.8.8
- Window 10 (64 bit)

**Steps followed**

- Created a virtual env named my_env using `virtualenv my_venv`
- `pip install sasl==0.3.1` after running this got error regarding Microsoft Visual Studio BuildTools.
- Then I installed MS BuildTools 2022 (restarted the PC as well), still on running again the `pip install sasl` command got error related to BuildTools.

**Error Log**

```
(base) (my_env) PS C:\Users\Tushar\Documents\experiments\virtual_venv> pip install sasl==0.3.1
Collecting sasl==0.3.1
  Using cached sasl-0.3.1.tar.gz (44 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\tushar\documents\experiments\virtual_venv\my_env\lib\site-packages (from sasl==0.3.1) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: sasl
  Building wheel for sasl (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\sasl
      copying sasl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\sasl
      running egg_info
      writing sasl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to sasl.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying sasl\saslwrapper.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\sasl
      copying sasl\saslwrapper.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\sasl
      copying sasl\saslwrapper.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\sasl
      running build_ext
      building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\sasl
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isasl -IC:\Users\Tushar\Documents\experiments\virtual_venv\my_env\include -Ic:\users\tushar\anaconda3\include -Ic:\users\tushar\anaconda3\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsasl/saslwrapper.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\sasl/saslwrapper.obj
      saslwrapper.cpp
      C:\Users\Tushar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_s2luv9_\sasl_28941ba9aeae476f8bf6801d946fb2d2\sasl\saslwrapper.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sasl/sasl.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sasl
  Running setup.py clean for sasl
Failed to build sasl
Installing collected packages: sasl
  Running setup.py install for sasl ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for sasl did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [30 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\Tushar\Documents\experiments\virtual_venv\my_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\sasl
      copying sasl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\sasl
      running egg_info
      writing sasl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to sasl.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying sasl\saslwrapper.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\sasl
      copying sasl\saslwrapper.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\sasl
      copying sasl\saslwrapper.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\sasl
      running build_ext
      building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\sasl
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isasl -IC:\Users\Tushar\Documents\experiments\virtual_venv\my_env\include -Ic:\users\tushar\anaconda3\include -Ic:\users\tushar\anaconda3\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsasl/saslwrapper.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\sasl/saslwrapper.obj
      saslwrapper.cpp
      C:\Users\Tushar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_s2luv9_\sasl_28941ba9aeae476f8bf6801d946fb2d2\sasl\saslwrapper.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sasl/sasl.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> sasl

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.1.2 -> 22.2.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
(base) (my_env) PS C:\Users\Tushar
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sasl` package contains `Cyrus-SASL bindings for Python` (see [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/sasl/)) It does not contain the `Cyrus-SASL` library though. Hence it cannot find the header file `'sasl/sasl.h'`. You will need to install that library, following the [official documentation](https://www.cyrusimap.org/sasl/sasl/windows.html#install-windows), but note that the windows support is not complete and it might therefore fail. I would suggest you look for a windows compatible alternative